# cv::gpu::GpuMat constructor fails if there is a thrust::reduce() call LATER in the code

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, thrust

I have a VS 2013 project where I use (somewhat outdated) OpenCV 2.4.9 and CUDA 7.5. What I discovered is that if a code contains some - but not all - `thrust` calls (`thrust::reduce()` in particular), then OpenCV GPU code stops working even though it executes BEFORE any `thrust` calls. In particular, `cv::gpu::GpuMat()` fails inside `cudaMallocPitch` call with access violation on `NULL` location. I'd like to know if I'm missing something before I urge everyone to upgrade to the latest OpenCV version. (Which might or might not help anyway.)

This is a more or less minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
// main.cu
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    float fc[arraySize] = { 0 };
    float* dev_c;

    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::eye(100,100,CV_32F);
    cv::gpu::GpuMat g(m);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, arraySize * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_c, fc, arraySize * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    thrust::device_ptr<float> dev_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(dev_c);
    // the line below works fine
    thrust::transform(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + arraySize, dev_ptr, dev_ptr, thrust::multiplies<float>());
    // the line below causes cv::gpu::GpuMat to crash, but the program works if it is commented
    float sum2 = thrust::reduce(dev_ptr, dev_ptr + arraySize, 0, thrust::plus<float>());
    cudaFree(dev_c);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not just running out of memory or resources? Compiling in a thrust call will greatly expand the amount of code and resources your application will require

Comment: Well, the problem was with the project settings. But how could it be a memory problem with just a couple thrust calls on a tiny array? That would make the library virtually unusable. Thanks anyway, I'm just learning CUDA and I'll need to learn how to monitor GPU resources as well.

Comment: On a smallish laptop GPU running a hardware accelerated display manager, you might have a couple of hundred Mb of free space for your CUDA app. The runtime must pre-allocate all the memory the runtime support requires (stack, per thread local memory, etc) before your app does anything on the GPU. How much depends on what code is compiled into your app. You would be amazed at how little memory can be left in some cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I decided to study the project settings, and by default CUDA code generation is set to `compute_20,sm_20`. I tried to change it to `compute_50,sm_50`, as I'm using GTX 750 Ti and OpenCV is also compiled with CUDA_ARCH_BIN set to 5.0, and now everything works.